# Why do I get an Error when I Retrieving Category menu?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Showing Error When I Retrieving Category.

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in
>   System.Web.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: An error occurred when trying to create a
>   controller of type 'OnlineDirectory.Controllers.NavController'. Make
>   sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor.

```
<div class="row panel">
    <div id="categories" class="col-xs-3">
        @Html.Action("Menu", "Nav")
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-8">
        @RenderBody()
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error couldn't be clearer. Your controller doesn't have a default constructor.

E.g:

```
// right - what you don't have
public HomeController() {
}

// wrong - what you DO have
public HomeController(IDependency dependency) {
}
```

By default, MVC requires a default parameterless constructor. This is because it doesn't know how to include dependencies.

To have dependencies injected, you must wire up your DI framework into MVC. How to do that depends on your container of choice.. which you haven't provided.